# File uploads; How to utilize "chunking"?

Tags: php, file-upload, chunking

I am (still) attempting to upload large files <200mb via a html form using php.

During my research into this I have come across the term "chunking", I understand that this process can break the file into handy sizes such as 5mb and reassemble them into the full file at the server side.

My problem seems to be where I can begin? I seem unable to find the correct resources by googling (Or perhaps I'm suffering from not knowing which terms to search for).

So what I'm hoping for today is a chance to educate myself with the basics, a direction in which to look would be very helpful. I don't really want to download a plug-in or anything like that, I would prefer to learn by experimentation.

> EDIT to add: ***Although the two answers below would appear to be correct, this takes me into the realm of stuff that I can't do as a designer...If anyone reading this can suggest a different approach I would appreciate it.***

Comment: I would suggest doing chunking via JavaScript. When JavaScript disabled only allow 20 MB or so. You can just google for "JavaScript chunked upload".

Answer (score 6):

Web browsers do not split uploads into chunks. For this you'll have to use your own "chunking" client: a Flash program or a Java applet.

You can take a look at [JUpload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupload/). There are also examples in the wiki.

> **From SourceForge :**
>
> Multiple File Upload Applet (JUpload) takes care of the limitation posed by traditional HTML upload forms by allowing you to upload a whole directory and the files within it with a single click. Optionally, it allows simple picture management.

Comment: @Justin @Heandel - Thanks, I did come across Jupload on my search but hoped the solution would be something I could do myself. That the actual "chunking" can not be handled by the browser explains why I found it so difficult to find a simple tutorial!

Comment: Apparently Chrome and Firefox 4+ support chunking (source:http://www.plupload.com/)