# Is php good for large file uploads such as videos

Tags: php, python, web

hi i wanted to know if uploading large files like videos ( over 200 mb - 1gb) from php is a good option after setting up the server configuration like max_post_size , execution time etc. The reason i ask this question is because i read some where that when a large file is uploaded , best practice is to break that file into chunks and upload it ( I think youtube does that). Do i need to use another language like python or C++ for uploading large files or is php enough. If i need to use another language can anyone please help me with reading material for that .

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864570/very-large-uploads-with-php
Here is a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will hold the entire file in memory while the upload is happening. That means that if you are uploading 5 files in parallel, then at the very most you will need 5GB+ of memory.

This can be done in PHP, and I have done this using a chunking method. There are several SO questions on this topic:

- [File uploads; How to utilize “chunking”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375852/file-uploads-how-to-utilize-chunking)
- [Upload 1GB files using chunking in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447837/upload-1gb-files-using-chunking-in-php)

But my personal preference is to use [plupload](http://www.plupload.com). It is a very complete cross-platform (JS, Flash, Silverlight) upload script with a nice PHP code sample to handle chunking.

Comment: thanks for your reply !! i need to know one more thing , as i want to build my own code for chunking can you help me with the resource on internet which can help me develop this feature !!

Comment: Yes. Download the plupload zip. The code is inside there. http://www.plupload.com/download.php

Answer (score 0):

Its not only `PHP` to be considered for large file uploads. Your web server also need to support that, at least in `nginx`. I don't know how `httpd` handles that, but as you said splitting in chunks are viable solution. `FTP` is another option.

Comment: thank you for your answer . but if i had a server as you mentioned and wanted to upload a file through chunks then can it be done in php or its better to use another language like python or c++.

Comment: Look at the reply by Under New Management, As I went through `plupload` pages, it looks impressive. You just need to add that in your `PHP` project, and not worry about extra scripting in Python or C++...