# html5: the upload task is interrupted in php

Tags: php, file-upload, large-files

I've got an alert message when trying to upload very large file in php. When I uploaded 53 MB file and 35% upload process complete, i got an alert message "html5: the upload task is interrupted". I don't know what does that mean. Can anyone help me out. Thank you.

Comment: check your `max_upload_size` parameter

Comment: i check it and it's set to 70 MB.

Answer (score 0):

**Method # 1: Edit php.ini**

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
     ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
     upload_max_filesize = 40M

     ; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
      post_max_size = 40M
```

Save and close the file. Restart apache or lighttpd web server:

**Method #2: Edit .htaccess**

Edit .htaccess file in your root directory. This is useful when you do not have access to php.ini file. In this example, /home/httpd/html is considered as root directory (you can also create .htaccess file locally and than upload it using ftp / sftp / scp client):

Append / modify setting as follows:

```
          php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
          php_value post_max_size 20M
          php_value memory_limit 32M
```

otherwise you prefer this link given below:-

1) **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)**
2)**[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102809/how-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php)**

i hope it helpful for you ...