# PHP execution timeout while uploading a large file to Google Drive with API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, executiontimeout

i want to upload a local file via PHP to Google Drive. If I upload a small file (<5MB) everything is working. If I want to upload a larger file I get a "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". I can set the max_execution_time in my php.ini on a very high value but it seems to be a bad solution. If I use "set_time_limit(seconds);" I can't upload more files simultaneously (I don't know why).

So my question is how to upload a large file without changing my php.ini to a bad execution time. How is that supposed to solve in PHP? I would like to use just a simple CURL cli command but that does not work with Google Drive because CURL can't support Oath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload large files above 500MB in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102809/how-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php)

Comment: i just want to use the google drive php api. it's not the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `max_execution_time` with `set_time_limit` is the right solution. If your script takes more than 30 seconds to upload the file, it **will** run more than 30 seconds.

```
set_time_limit(600); //File upload should not take longer than 10 minutes
do_your_file_upload();
set_time_limit(30); //Change it back to 30 seconds for further processing
```

> I can't upload more files simultaneously

Can you specify what you mean?

If you cannot reach your PHP-Script while the other one runs, it is often because of [PHP session management](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). When you start the session with [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) PHP (creates and) opens the session file and **locks it for writing**. The file will be locked until your scripts calls [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) or the script execution ends. To work with two or more sessions simultaneously, you have to call [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php):

```
session_start();
//do stuff
session_write_close();

set_time_limit(600); //File upload schould not take longer than 10 minutes
do_your_file_upload();
set_time_limit(30); //Change it back to 30 seconds for further processing

session_start();
//do more stuff
session_write_close();
```

Comment: I had two identical scripts a.php and b.php running at the same time. Both of them start a session and both of them upload the same file but with different names. Both of them failed.

Comment: Any error messages? If not, give use some code to review.

Answer (score 0):

This a bad idea to use a simple PHP code to upload a very large file.

You should use Javascript to upload large files because it's using AJAX methods. Also, it will allow you to display a progress bar.

I did a little research. Here is some nice scripts using jQuery :
http://designscrazed.org/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/

Or another script which not use jQuery (I don't if it's a good one) :
http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

Good luck !

Comment: That's simply not what i want. I want to upload a file to Google Drive. Therefore i need to use Googles APIs. The script is also running on a server with no browser. That's why i can't use javascript (there is no offline access in js api).