# Unable to Upload Large files through Plesk in PHP as error says "Connection was reset"

Tags: php, plesk

I m trying to upload large video files (1.5 to 2GB) through my website hosted in Plesk, however, even after changing the PHP settings as

`memory_limit to 5000M`
`max_execution_time to 12000`
`max_input_time to 12000`
`post_max_size to 5000M`
`upload_max_filesize to 5000M`

However, If the files of size 100MB are uploading well.

it still gives me the same error as "**Site can't be reached - The connection was reset**"

FYI,

```
 Hosting in **Plesk**

 PHP version **7.2.33**

 Run PHP as **FPM Application Served by Apache**
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure domain is live? Site can't be reached seems to be a different problem.

Comment: yes, it is, on the other hand, If i m to upload a video of 100 MB it goes well. the problem rises when i try to upload large file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload large files above 500MB in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102809/how-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php)