# Getting 413 Request Entity too large error while Posting 500k-100K lines from textarea

Tags: php, apache

I m trying to post 500K-100K lines from textarea and insert it in mysql table line by line.

But I'm getting error;

413 Request Entity too Large.

The request resource /action.php does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a 413 Request Entity Too Large error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: error seems clear... 500k in a post is crazy, why not do a file upload?

Comment: I had added file upload functionality also, which is working fine.

Comment: You need to use `POST` method instead of `GET`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I had used POST but dont know why the error is showing GET

Comment: so if you have a file uplaod why do you need 500k in an textarea?

Comment: refer to this post [Work around Error 413 request entity too large](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40212229/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

Apache length of the request line default limit is 8190, thats why you get this error when passing $_GET parameter. Use $_POST instead then you only need to handle script execution time and memory. By the way some old browsers like IE6 can handle only about 2000 request line length so increase it in apache configs won't help.