# Ajax response is null while uploading a large image file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I am doing the drag image using dropzone plugin .

Here everything is working fine ,but when i am going to upload a large file ,ajax response is null .For small mb image file it is coming fine ,response is coming and working fine.

I have echoed the

```html
pr($_FILES);exit;//for large image file it is null
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

}
else
{

}
```

I am getting an empty array .Here ajax post is coming fine.
I am not getting what is the error ,
For small size image 
[image]
For large size image
[image]
Any suggestion ?
Thank you

Comment: Have you check to see what the max upload size is in the server config files?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to increase the upload limit on the server

Comment: yes i have checked ,it is 128M and my post_max_size = 8M @Blinkydamo

Comment: I have uploaded a file of 30.4MB ,but its not working

Comment: Have you changed both of these to what you need? `; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M`

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 8M
@Blinkydamo

Comment: That might be your issue then, change the post_max_size to 128M and reload the server.

Comment: Ok ,I am also thinking of this.

Answer (score 0):

By configuration, PHP only allows to upload files up to a certain size.

You can edit your php.ini file and set

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

then restart your server

If you are trying to upload file greater than 2 GB. Then you should consider the memory usage of such a script.

Then you have to user chunked upload.More details : [Handling plupload's chunked uploads on the server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011138/handling-pluploads-chunked-uploads-on-the-server-side) and here : [File uploads; How to utilize "chunking"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375852/file-uploads-how-to-utilize-chunking)